# MYSQL Order by case and name

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm looking to build a query that basically orders by category, orders by specific names when applicable and finally order by bvaaa_iw_bulk from all bvaaa_name fields. I can't seem to combine both a case and other order statements. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_bvaaa_table
WHERE bvaaa_category='3'
ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN bvaaa_subcategory = '2' THEN '1'
             ELSE bvaaa_subcategory
         END,
ORDER BY FIELD(bvaaa_name, 'Orange', 'Brown')
        , bvaaa_iw_bulk ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use one ORDER BY keyword. However you can order by multiple columns. eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_bvaaa_table
WHERE bvaaa_category='3'
ORDER BY if (bvaaa_subcategory = '2', '1', bvaaa_subcategory),
FIELD(bvaaa_name, 'Orange', 'Brown'),
bvaaa_iw_bulk;
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about whats happening at the if. What is the 2 and 1?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is same as your orignial CASE. same thing

Comment: So a couple of questions. How would you expand that to other cases?

`if(bvaaa_subcategory = '2', '1', bvaaa_subcategory),
if(bvaaa_sub...`

As far as the field section. Is that creating an order? It seems they end up on the bottom of the list. Can you explain a little about what is happening there? 

Thanks a lot for your help by the way.

Comment: Forgot to add DESC on order issue. Good news there. Still confused about the if section.

Comment: Yes, anything after ORDER BY separated by COMA is an order list

Comment: Yes, you can add DESC to any of them. In your case, the IF and CASE produced exactly the same result. please check MySQL manual on IF

Comment: if (condition, true, false)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101107/discussion-between-hfw-and-sidu).